# What is this type of ribbon connector called? I need to see if I can get this made

Tags: identification

This is the contact area for my motorcycle intercom.  A couple of the contact points have corroded to the point where the metal has gone. I need to try and find a company who could maybe make this so I can fix it, as the intercom is fine other than this contact pad.

What is this called so I can search online for services?

[image]

Comment: That is not a ribbon cable cable. That is a rigid printed circuit board with square, unpinned pads. It mechanically locks into another device with "pogo pins" that make contact.

Comment: It doesn't look too badly corroded - still seems to be intact. Get a slightly abrasive pencil eraser to clean the pads.

Comment: Well, the pin in the bottom left corner seems to be having a life of its own. Maybe it could be loose or bent?

Comment: I have tried scraping the corrosion off, doesn't seem to help. Is there a way these can be restored?

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer? Even if they say no, it should at least alert them to an issue with the product.

Comment: Have you opened it to see what is connected on the other side of the board?

Comment: Without even knowing what you paid for that device  I can guarantee that the cost to have someone reverse-engineer the damaged piece and produce a replacement would be 10x to 100x whatever it costs for you to just buy a new one.

Comment: @MartynBall If you very keen to get it working, you could re-create the PCB in KiCad and get it manufactured by one of those companies that does PCBs quite cheaply such as PCBWay or JLCPCB. You could specify thicker copper (e.g. 2oz.) and gold plating. We have no idea what is on the other side of the PCB.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I asked if they offered refurbishment but they said no. They do supply 2 year warranty, but that has expired.

The device is a Sena 30k Intercom. 

I will open it soon and have a look what it's like the other side. They are around £250, so don't really want to pay for a new one over a simple connection issue, even though it could be a pain to fix.